# I need to return rows based on 19 columns of the same data positions of the same condition in SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table with 19 columns of the same content and need to return rows that do not have certain values in one or the other.  But when I use (proc1 NOT IN ('xxxxx','xxxxx') or proc2 not in ('xxxxx','xxxxx') or proc3 etc) I still see rows with one of the values. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `and` instead of `or`

Comment: I should add that the 19 columns have a unique value of the same type.  For example. Diagnosis Code.

Comment: I tried that too but let me try again.  I even tried NOT(proc_cd in ('xxxxx','xxxxx')  Let you know....  Thanks!!!

Comment: @Jonathan thanks...my first question and got a message how to reply

Comment: If you still have a problem, please edit your question with some sample data and enough columns to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment so I will write here
Did you try:

```
SELECT *
 FROM `table`
 WHERE `col1` NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', `col2`, '%')
```